# Npgsql EF Core (.NET 6) is extremely slow (EF Core + Postgres, Database-First)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, npgsql

There is a problem with queries to existing Postgres database using Npgsql EF Core (.NET 6). Even simple EF queries are extremely slow (from 25  sec to several minutes for big expressions). At the same time generated SQL code executes in 20-50 milliseconds. Database is a little bit ugly and not very normalized, but SQL queries execute quite quickly. Also (if it is important) db is not big, smth abount 40.000 rows in some biggest tables.

Here is simple EF query, it takes 24 seconds:

```
var list = await context.SomeObjects
            .Include(x => x.FirstJoinedEntity)
            .Include(x => x.SecondJoinedEntity)
            .Include(x => x.ThirdJoinedEntity)
            .ToListAsync();
```

It generates quite simple SQL and it takes about 160 ms to load all rows:

```
SELECT "A lot of columns"
FROM some_object AS o
     LEFT JOIN first AS f ON o.id = f.object_id
     LEFT JOIN second AS s ON o.id = s.object_id
     LEFT JOIN third AS t ON o.id = t.object_id
```

Very simple and fast.

Is there any profiler which can show what exactly takes a lot of time in EF Core Npgsql? Or any way how to just understand why EF Core slows so much? I can't change it to code-first and recreate database, but tried Npgsql command to autogenerate Context and all entities for exisiting database to match all Postgres -> C# types:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

But it didn't help: result is the same.

The question is how to diagnose reason of that problem.

Comment: How many rows are being returned in your queries?  In your first example, it will return all rows in the database multiplied by the 3 other joins (no Where or Take to reduce it).

Comment: @Neil Yes, first query returns all data from table (39, 000 rows) in 24 seconds. The problem is why SQL, that is generated by that expression loads all this small table in 162 ms. This is the question, that affects all other business logic with .Where() and .Take().

Comment: Just to verify: so mean that the query including all columns EF puts there runs in 160ms? And what's the number of rows in the result set? You may have a [cartesian explosion here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) which may give EF a lot of data to crunch in materializing entity objects.

Comment: Loading 39K rows into memory at once is a really bad idea.  Unless you have loads of RAM, and are planning on some heavy duty calculations on it all, there should be no need to do it.   You can use the IAsyncEnumerable style queries, but I don't think that's the answer to your problem, you just need to reduce the number of rows you are requesting.